# Change Behaviour of Tablet Mode

Tags: tablet

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my Asus C302 laptop. The laptop is a 2-in-1 convertible, where the screen can be rotated to make the laptop into a tablet.

When I rotate the screen into 'tablet mode', Ubuntu disables the trackpad, but the keyboard remains enabled. How I can also disable the keyboard on the tablet mode event?

Many thanks.

Comment: Boot an ubuntu version 18.10 or later, then try `sudo modprobe chromeos_tbmc` in the terminal.  Does that fix your problem?